# How to send a notification to specific users through Firebase Cloud Messaging in Jetpack Compose

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app that when a user add something to the database I want it to send a notification to some specific users. Basically my app have 2 types of users: "Users" and "Admin", when a regular user send a warning through the app, it stores in the database and I want it to send a notification to the "Admins" to alert that a user sent a warning. The accounts that are considered "Admins" have their email stored in a collection of the firestore.

I tried to follow the documentation that the firebase provides, but i can only send the test  notifications from the firebase console. I am getting the device token right, I have all dependencies and implementation the class to handle the cloud messaging is in the android manifest. At this point I have tested so many things but the only results I get are nothing or the app crashing. I dont even know if what I want is possible and if it is if its done in the app or in the firebase.

This is the code that I have in the Cloud Messaging Class:

```
class CloudMessaging : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, token)
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        message.from?.let { Log.d(TAG, it) }
    }


}

fun sendNotificationToDevice(title: String, message: String) {
    val firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()

    val remoteMessage = RemoteMessage.Builder("my token")
        .addData("title", title)
        .addData("body", message)
        .build()

    try {
        firebaseMessaging.send(remoteMessage)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

In the onMessageReceived theres a log just to see if something happens if im in the app,
"my token" was my devices token
I was calling the sendNotificationToDevice function where the event should trigger the notification

Comment: You need to some how get the admins token in the users app and in the admins application you subscribe to topic containing the admins token then in the users application you can use the admins token to send the notification. You can refer to this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoFWPPv1ih8

Comment: If you understand Java, maybe this [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA) will help.

Comment: Overall those resources are getting outdated with firebase constantly updating and I am not understanding how to use that Java resource properly in Kotlin